# How do I import packages and modules in Python without any errors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, module

I am trying to import tensorflow, matplotlib, numpy, and keras. When I try to do this I get an error saying that the module does not exist.

I have tried installing the latest version of everything as well as reinstalling them.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = keras.dataset_fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.data_load()

print(train_labels[1])
```

I expect the output to be a number between 1 and 10.

There might be an error such as:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>python "tensorflow.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Note that this is not the only module that is having issues. Same thing happens with numpy and tensorflow.

Comment: Have you installed the package(s)?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that...

Comment: How did you install them? Are they present in the output of `python -m pip freeze`?

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi have you installed them using venv or conda or installed it globally for Python?

Comment: Yes, I installed them using pip install --pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip {package}. Yes, they are all in the output of ```python -m pip freeze```.

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi Another guess is - try to rename file from `tensorflow.py` to something other than library name.

Comment: I am not sure if I have installed them globally. I don't know how you even do that. I did not use venv.

Comment: I changed the file name to helloworld and ran it. It gave me the output of ``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
``` @wowkin2

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? I've had problems with pip referring to a different version of python than the one I am running. Looks like you are on Windows, are you running from powershell?

Comment: I am running from command prompt. I installed the latest version of Python and I uninstalled everything from the previous version. @ufoxDan

Comment: What is the ouptut of `where python` and `where pip`?

Comment: @ufoxDan
For where python :
```
C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
```
For where pip:
```
C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `where` is showing a pip in /Python37 first and your python is in /Python37-32 your calls to pip and python are not the same python version. You can remove the Python37 folder from your PATH to fix this.

Go to Start Menu and search "Change system environment variable", select edit variable or something of the like and then remove the other python folder from your PATH variables. You will have to reopen cmd after this is done.

Comment: I fixed it, never mind. I selected edit on the Path but there is no Python37 only Python37-32

Comment: I uninstalled Python37 and used Python37-32 but I still get the error.

Comment: Can you try using `where` on pip and python again? If it shows pip in two places still then share a screenshot of your PATH variables because it would be in there somewhere.

Comment: ```
C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe
```